# Cannot run servlet on eclipse, java virtual machine error & "starting tomcat localhost has encountered problem"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am new to tomcat and java servlet development. I have followed instructions from every youtube tutorial videos, Java guidebook, and all, but I cannot seem to successfully run servlets. Running Tomcat works perfectly when I run it from the command prompt (using the startup command), and I am able to see the apache tomcat website with http://localhost:8080. However, when I am trying to run my servlets on eclipse, it always first says that it cannot create Java Virtual Machine, and when I press ok to this error, I see another window telling me that "starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem."

First, for Java Virtual Machine error, it tells me on the console that "Endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs." I did a bit of research on this and I tried deleting some lines and modifying Catalina.sh file, following another stack overflow answer. But this didn't seem to work. I also tried making an environmental variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the value of -Xmx512M and that didn't stop from seeing the same error message.

With the second error of "starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost has encountered problem", I am not sure why it shows up because the tomcat runs fine from the command prompt, as I said.

I am very frustrated, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try removing the -Djava.endorsed.dirs option from the Debug configuration for the server in Eclipse

Comment: @TomazFernandes Could you please provide me a bit more detailed information on how I can do so? I am currently in Debug configuration, but I am not sure how I can find -Djava.endorsed.dirs and delete it.

Comment: Can you post your Eclipse Debug configuration? Also, what JDK version are you using?

Comment: Use an older release of Java, like Java 8, or use a newer version of Eclipse, like 2019-12.